# get textbox vlaue in php on same page using get method

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, get

Hi am tryimg to get the  texbox value on same page  in php when i submit form using selectbox onchange event but i am not able toa chieve this.

Here is my code

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      function ChooseContact(data) {
         document.getElementById ("friendName1").value = data.value;
      }
  </script>
  <?php
    if(($_GET)) {
      $users1 = $_GET['category3'];
      echo $users1;
      echo "shakti";
    }
  ?>    
  <form action="test.php" method="get">
    <select name="district"  id="district"  onchange="ChooseContact(this);this.form.submit();">
      <option selected="selected" value="">--Select--</option>
      <option selected="selected" value="hi">--hi--</option>
      <option selected="selected" value="hello">--hello--</option>
    </select>
 <input  type="text" id="friendName1"  name="category3" value="<?php echo $mysub;?> ">
      </form>
```

How can i acieve  my output

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$mysub` inside the input seems to be undefind. Also the `$users1` is undefined, when there's no `$_GET`

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function ChooseContact(data) {
     document.getElementById ("friendName1").value = data.value;
  }
</script>
<?php
  $users1 = '';
  if(($_GET)) {
    $users1 = $_GET['category3'];
    echo $users1;
    echo ' shakti';
  }
?>    
<form action="" method="get">
 <select name="district"  id="district"  onchange="ChooseContact(this);this.form.submit();">
   <option selected="selected" value="">--Select--</option>
   <option value="hi">--hi--</option>
   <option value="hello">--hello--</option>
 </select>
 <input  type="text" id="friendName1"  name="category3" value="<?php echo $users1;?> ">
</form>
```

Comment: its working good  only 1st time when page submit  again when i selecect last optioin does not work

Answer (score 0):

First at all, your `category3` input isnt in the `<form>` Element.

Then you shoud use the `$_GET` variable instead of `$_get` (if you havent defined `$_get` then it doesnt exists) or `$_POST` because you are submitting the form with the `GET` method

Comment: @sheetalsharma I still dont see the `category3` input inside of the `<form>`

Answer (score 0):

First of all `$_get` doesn't exist. There is `$_GET`.

Also you have to decide if you want to use `POST` or `GET`. Data is sent using `GET` but you are trying to access it in `$_POST` array.

Answer (score 0):

the `category3` post does not eixst.
You can use it like this with your `<select name="xxx"><option ....></select>`
However in your case your `$_POST` should be `$_GET['district']`